# Configure Spring Security to use custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have implemented my own `LowerCaseUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` that is just a subclass of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

But now my problem is, how to configure Spring security to use this filter.

Up to now I used:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="${cfma.security.channel}" />
</security:http>
```

Do I really to turn of `auto-config` and need to configure all the filters by hand? - If this is true, does anybody can provide an example please?

---

The way to add simply a `security:custom-filter`:

```
<security:http ...>

   <security:form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
   <security:custom-filter ref="lowerCaseUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
   ...
 </security:http>
```

does result in an exception with that message:

> Configuration problem: Filter beans `<lowerCaseUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter>` and 'Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null' have the same 'order' value. **When using custom filters, please make sure the positions do not conflict with default filters.** Alternatively you can disable the default filters by removing the corresponding child elements from  and avoiding the use of .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have done it by writing the needed autoconfigured beans by hand. This is the result:

```
<!-- HTTP security configurations -->
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">

    <!--
    <security:form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
        replaced by lowerCaseUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
        the custom-filter with position FORM_LOGIN_FILTER requries that auto-config is false!
     -->
    <security:custom-filter ref="lowerCaseUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    <security:logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>

<bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login"/>
</bean>

<bean id="lowerCaseUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
    class="com.queomedia.cfma.infrastructure.security.LowerCaseUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/resources/j_spring_security_check"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login?login_error=t"/>       
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example in Scala.   I had to do this to replace a filter provided by Spring Security OAuth.

Basically the idea is, inject the `FilterChainProxy` and the existing filter that you want to replace into your filter.   Find the existing filter in the `filterChainMap` and replace it with yours.

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.verification.{VerificationCodeFilter => SpringVerificationCodeFilter}

@Component
class VerificationCodeFilter extends SpringVerificationCodeFilter with InitializingBean {
  @Autowired var filterChainProxy: FilterChainProxy = _
  @Autowired var springVerificationCodeFilter: SpringVerificationCodeFilter = _


  override def afterPropertiesSet() {
    super.afterPropertiesSet()

    val filterChainMap = filterChainProxy.getFilterChainMap
    val filterChain = 
       filterChainMap.find(_._2.exists(_.isInstanceOf[SpringVerificationCodeFilter])).
          getOrElse(throw new Exception("Could not find VerificationCodeFilter in FilterChainMap"))._2
    val index = filterChain.indexOf(springVerificationCodeFilter)
    filterChain.remove(index)
    filterChain.add(index, this)
  }
}
```